# Non-commutative multiplication sign and constant treatment

Tags: function-construction, operators

By default, non-commutative multiplication behaves as

```
(-W) ** (4 R) //FullForm
```

> `NonCommutativeMultiply[Times[-1,W],Times[4,R]]`

while I would like it to simplify as follows, for any object involved that is not a symbol:

```
(-W) ** (4 R) //FullForm
```

> `Times[-4,NonCommutativeMultiply[W,R]`]

I could write a set of substitution rules, but I suspect that would be very slow for large number of operations. How should one set this property the most efficient way? Perhaps there is a proper `Attribute` one can set for `NonCommutativeMultiply`?

EDIT

Since in my case only products of two operators appear at a time, I use the following as a workaround

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
NonCommutativeMultiply[Times[x1_,y1_],Times[x2_,y2_]]:= Times[x1,x2,NonCommutativeMultiply[y1,y2]]
```

Mathematica seems to order `Times` as constants first then symbols, which is why this works.

Still wondering how a better more efficient solution would look like.

Comment: Try `Times @@ MapThread[Apply, {{Times, NonCommutativeMultiply}, Transpose[FactorTermsList /@ {-W, 4 R}]}]`. Generalization ought to be straightforward.

Comment: @J.M. Wow, that line of code looks quite busy... I wonder if that would be the most efficient way for large inputs?

Comment: How large are we talking?

Comment: @J.M. Millions of operations. Preferably per second...

Comment: Something large like `a1 ** a2 ** ... ** a1000000`, then?

Comment: @J.M. more like a1 ** a2 + a3 ** a4 + ... actually. And then the result of that taken as new a1, a2 etc for next iteration.

Comment: @J.M. the problem seems to be that while `NonCommutativeMultiply` is properly distributive with respect to summation, it is however not so for constant multiplication...

Comment: You might want to add a constraint like `Times[x1_?NumericQ, y1_]` for safety.